# Introducing user specific timezones in existing high-traffic web app?

Tags: timezone

Long story short, we developed a web app for internal use and one thing led to another and now it's a SaaS with over 1,000 users. Problem is that everything date-related (which is a lot!) is hard-coded to Pacific time (don't ask) and users obviously want their own timezones.

I've read up on the best way to manage timezones in web apps, but still not sure on the best way forward with our existing, live, mission-critical web app used by over 1,000 businesses...

I guess the big "problem" is just that we're talking about 100k+ lines of code, and probably at least 100 different DB queries that are date related.

From what I've read, it seems like the "correct" way to manage timezones is to store everything in UTC and then convert to the users TZ on output ...

But at this point would there be anything wrong with simply modifying all the date-related queries and basically wrapping all the dates with MySQL's convert_tz to convert from the existing PDT timestamps to the user's timezone?

As far as I can tell if we converted all the date fields in the DB to UTC and changed MySQL to run under UTC we'd have to do the same thing anyway, so is there any particular reason to convert all the existing date fields to UTC at this point?

Answer (score 2):

Well, "correct" depends a lot on what your application does, and what the date in your application is used for.  In many scenarios, storing as UTC and converting to the user's time zone is exactly what is needed.  But not all of them.

For example, if your dates are part of a recurrence pattern for scheduling future events, then you *wouldn't* use UTC for that.

As another example, if you have date-only fields, then those dates are likely "business days" which might be based on the user's time zone, but might be based on your business's time zone.

The most general case of storing as UTC is when you are referring to a unambiguous instant in time, such as storing a timestamp of when something actually happened (past tense).

So getting back to your question - why not just base it on Pacific time?  Well, Pacific time isn't fixed like UTC is.  It is UTC-8 in the winter during PST, and UTC-7 in the summer during PDT.  Because of this, every year there is a one-hour gap where local time is missing, and a one-hour overlap where local time is duplicated.  You can read more about this in [the daylight saving time tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/dst/info).

I recommend you take the following approach:

- Create a new column in your database table for the UTC time
- Write some code to adjust the local time to UTC.  Use the daylight saving time transitions [shown here](http://www.timeanddate.com/time/change/usa/los-angeles?syear=1980&eyear=2014) to determine whether to add 8 hours or 7 hours to calculate the UTC time.  Copy the adjusted value to the new field.
- Manually revisit values that fall into the fall-back overlap.  For Pacific time, that's between `1:00:00.000` and `1:59:59.999` on the DST end date.  You may need to adjust these values manually, as they could belong to either PDT or PST.  To disambiguate, see if you have any other values to consider.  For example, if you have an auto-incrementing primary key, then when sorted by that key, the timestamps should be roughly sequential.
- Now that you have the new column for UTC, start converting all of your code to use it.
- Eventually, you can remove the old column.

Comment: Sorry forgot to ask - can you tell me what would be wrong with simply leaving everything as is and just wrapping all the dates in our select queries with MySQL's convert_tz function? Wouldn't that properly convert from the existing Pacific time to the user's timezone?

Comment: Ack I'm sorry but I just realized something else. We only recently made this app available to the public and it was just after this past DST change on May 9th so we haven't been through a DST change yet.

I assume this presents us with a unique opportunity to "fix" this in an easier way before the next DST change?

Comment: DST came in on March 9th, but the gap isn't the issue.  The bigger issue is the overlap on November 2nd.  That's where the ambiguous data can occur.  UTC to Local is deterministic, but Local to UTC is not because of the overlap.  Leaving it as is would not take that into account.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. Sorry yeah I meant March 9th. I hear what you're saying, but doesn't MySQL's convert_tz function take the gap and overlap into account when it converts from one TZ to another? I thought it did, so I guess I'm still having a hard time seeing where the problem lies with that approach ...?

Comment: Another idea...

What if we just create a function whereby when the user selects a different timezone, the system would just go through all the relevant tables and change the value of all their existing timestamps via MySQL's convert_tz function? The system would also obviously start logging all new timestamps going forward in their selected timezone.

Making this change wouldn't take more than a handful of hours, whereas if we do what you're suggesting I estimate ~100 hours to go through all the code, make all the necessary changes, and then test everything before we can go live with it.

Comment: Whatever path you take, you should test it out on non-live data first.  Regarding convert_tz - that's fine, but it will still have ambiguities if a value falls into the fall-back overlap.

Comment: I get it now. Even if we didn't need to implement this new feature and we did nothing at all, we'd still have an "issue" come November 9th due to the overlap when the server and MySQL fall back an hour. Honestly, in this particular case, one hour of overlap once a year is not that big of a deal ... and probably doesn't warrant 100+ hours of work to eliminate. Thanks for all your input.